# write a cfg for the regular expression r=(a+b)*aa(a+b)*

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

CFG for Regular Expression `r=(a+b)*aa(a+b)*`
I wrote the production as

```
 P:   S -> SaaS|aS|bS|E
```

and my other friends wrote

```
 P: S -> AaaA
    A -> aA|bA|E
```

Please, Which one is Correct?Its for a test. Will I get any mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've got it wrong. Notice that the grammar you wrote accepts the empty string. And clearly the regular expression requires at least `aa` to be present in the string. The second version makes sure this is indeed the case. Better luck next time!